# App binary created with xcode 7.0.1 is not finding on itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode7

I uploaded a build before 20 hours on iTunes it was showing submitted successfully. But until now there is no build even if + icon is not there. I know processing is shown. Is there any policy upgrade by iTunes connect.

Comment: Same issue faced by me yesterday. I uploaded the same build again with the same version and the problem was solved.

Comment: Hello Leena how you solved this problem

Comment: I submitted again the same version on the app store and it got uploaded. Try once again

Comment: try another browser..i tried in chrome..chrome may be helped

Comment: Maulik, I tried on chrome and safari but it still not showing + icon